# A question about the router ID for EIGRP

Tags: cisco, routing, router, eigrp

If I configure a loopback interface and then set a router id by typing, `eigrp router-id 10.0.0.1`, for example, and the router protocol is EIGRP, what will be the accurate id for this router if the ID I set is higher than the loopback address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specifically set the router ID, then that is what the router ID will be.

[*Chapter: EIGRP Commands*](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/iproute/command/reference/fiprrp_r/1rfeigrp.html):

> ### Defaults
>
> EIGRP automatically selects an IP address to use as the router ID when
>   an EIGRP process is started. The highest local IP address is selected
>   and loopback interfaces are preferred. The router ID is not changed
>   unless the EIGRP process is removed with the **no router eigrp**
>   command or if the router ID is manually configured with the **eigrp
>   router-id** command.